# Structure of だから地味になっているかというと、そんなことはなかった

Tags: grammar

I've studied Japanese a long time ago and decided to pick it up again. I'm reading from this novel but I want to make sure if I'm reading this sentence right. I having issues when sentences are long.

> ただ、だから地味になっているかというと、そんなことは全くなかった。
>   However, so having said that it comes out modest, that sort of thing is not entirely so.

Comment: Part by part I can see where you're coming from in your translation, but I have no idea how to make sense of the full sentence in English, so I find it hard to assess whether you've correctly understood the sentence in Japanese.

Comment: Second thoughts, I think you're definitely misinterpreting だから, but I still think it's worth to give a natural sounding translation.

Comment: How about something like "However, you can't say, that this is the reason it got that simple/modest."?

Comment: [Sentence 1] かというと、 [Sentence 2] is used to assert that a popular belief in Sentence 1 is not right. So it denies that "the thing" (?) is simple (plan, rustic, subdued) and asserts that it's not all there is to it? It would be a bit easier to see if you added the sentences that came before and after.

Comment: Sorry about that, the previous sentence which I cannot find where it was again. Talked about her autumn clothing. Part after this one was talking about how fitted her clothing was and how it showed her body features.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are someone who is already reading novels in Japanese, I will be on the strict side.

You should have provided more context either in actual words used or in the form of a side note.  Why do I say this?  Because we have asbolutely no idea what the thing/object/phenomenon is that is being talked about.

So, what is it that the speaker is judging whether or not it is [地味]{じみ}になっている?  Because 「地味」 has a few very different meanings, it is imperative that one know what the thing is that we are talking about in order to do a good translation.

> "As for whether or not it had become more 地味, however, that was not the case at all."
>
> = It had not become more 地味.

Depending on what the thing is, 「地味」 could be translated to:

"simple", "quiet", "subdued", "reserved", "restrained", "sober", "plain", etc.

I hope you can see my point now.

Comment: Sorry about that, the previous sentence which I cannot find where it was again. Was talking about her autumn clothes. I was thinking modest might of been the proper word for it when I was looking for the word in my dictionary.